# Quadratic Equation in Big-Oh Notation

Tags: recursion, runtime, big-o, recurrence

I am reviewing for a midterm test regarding Big-Oh runtime. One of the questions I have difficulty with is given the following recurrence and the question is asking for the Big-Oh notation.

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (2n^2 + 3n + 5)

So by using the Master Theorem, where k > log_b (a), in this question, I am thinking **k** is 2 from (2n^2), **a** is 2 from 2T and **b** is 2 from (n/2). Therefore, the runtime of Master Theorem is when k > log_b (a), that is 2 > log_2 (2) = 1, then T(n) = O(n^2).

Is my thinking correct? I have never seen a quadratic runtime inside T(n) but I am fairly certain it is O(n^2) in this question.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, O(n^2) is correct. Actually there is a similar example in the [Wikipedia article about the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_3_example). This function could be anything and basically you just compare the depth and width of the recursion tree with the cost of this additional function and check what is dominating the complexity.